# Double "group by" without join?

Tags: sql, hive

I have user data:

```
user  store  item  cost
1     10     100   5
1     10     101   3
1     11     102   7
2     10     101   3
2     12     103   4
2     12     104   5
```

I want a table which will tell me for each user how much he bought from each store and how much he bought in total:

```
user store  cost_this_store  cost_total
1    10     8                15
1    11     7                15
2    10     3                12
2    12     9                12
```

I can do this with two `group by` and a `join`:

```
select s.user, s.store, s.cost_this_store, u.cost_total
from (select user, store, sum(cost) as cost_this_store
      from my_data
      group by user, store) s
join (select user, sum(cost) as cost_total
      from my_data
      group by user) u
on s.user = u.user
```

However, this is definitely not how I would do this if I were writing this in any other language (`join` is clearly avoidable, and the two `group by` are not independent).
Is it possible to avoid the `join` in `sql`?

PS. I need the solution to work in `hive`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with a [windowing function](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics)... which Hive added support for last year:

```
select distinct
  user, 
  store, 
  sum(cost) over (partition by user, store) as cost_this_store,
  sum(cost) over (partition by user) as cost_total
from my_data
```

However, I'd argue that there wasn't anything glaringly wrong with your original implementation.  You've essentially got two different sets of data, which you're combining through a `JOIN`.

The duplication might look like a code smell in a different language, but this isn't necessarily the wrong approach in SQL, and often you'll have to take approaches such as this that duplicate a portion of a query between two intermediate result sets for performance reasons.

[SQL Fiddle (SQL Server)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/46c9f/12)

Comment: @sds Yea... If it gives you the results you need, and it runs quickly enough for you... I'd say go with it.

Comment: but it will not run "quickly enough"! `join` is expensive!

Comment: @sds I'm not familiar with Hive specificially, but `Join` operations are essentially what RBDMSs are built to do, and assuming proper indexing, they do so with surprising efficiency.  I wouldn't worry about the overhead of an additional `join`... even if you did have the option of the windowing function, it would probably take a similar execution plan to the query containing the `join`.

Comment: alas, hive does _not_ have a notion of an index; a join is an extra MR job.